# Easy way to keep two SQL Servers synced if you have read only access to publisher (source) of data

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-replication

I am making C# app that rely on data from one old SQL Server 2005 machine.

Since I have only acces to read only data from that server, I need to build up some kind of handmade replication.

My app is going to use SQL Server 2012 and I am planing to read data from old SQL server in nightly tasks.

Before I start reinventing the well for sync data between two SQL Servers, I'll love to try to find some kind of library or system which can do the JOB.

Unfortunately I can't just setup replication between two SQL Servers because source of data is at SQL Server 2005 version and I do not have admin rights on that server.

I just need few tables to keep sync (updated) at my new SQL Server.

Is there some kind of embedded replication which can be called from code, and which have no needs for writing and admin access to publisher database?

Comment: Maybe RhinoETL http://ayende.com/blog/3102/rhino-etl-2-0

Comment: Requests for third-party products are off-topic for SO, but you could build a solution in SSIS.

Comment: Take a look at the [Sync Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726002(v=sql.105).aspx).  You can set this up to do a one-way replication.  This will require that extension of Sql Server installed on the database server machine (not the publishing server, don't worry)  and you can then perform a sync that pulls updates.